# Enable file sharing for app from iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes

Generally when I connect a iPhone to my computer, iTunes detects it and there is a option for File Sharing in iTunes which can be used to share files from the system to iPhone apps.

[image: File Sharing example]

I am using an app called "Don't Touch This - Secret Data Vault". How can I enable the file sharing option for this app?

I followed this article but it is no use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app

Answer (score 1):

You can't, it's up to the app developer to implement the feature.